# Проблемы с console.log

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

В консоли ничего не отображается(версия браузера последняя, с кодировкой все порядке, файл с расширением .html).

Работает лишь в том случае, если подключить html файлу js файл.

Настройки console(в самом хроме)

console {debug: ƒ, error: ƒ, info: ƒ, log: ƒ, warn: ƒ, …}

Возможно тут что-то неправильно, подскажите как изменить их.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видимо фильтр в консоли настроен. Сверху справа в окне консоли написано "1 item hidden by filters"

Comment: Как изменить фильтр консоли?У меня какой-то фильтр скрыт и не знаю что делать

Comment: Я вот тоже смотрю, вроде как всё норм. Может быть в поле поиска написано слово Filter?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отладка не работает в хроме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708690/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5)

Comment: ↑ Я вам уже рассказывал в прошлый раз, что нужно сделать.

Comment: С другой стороны, то, что я рассказывал, может не помочь, но вы тогда хотя бы ответьте, что вам это не помогает, вместо того чтобы делать копию вопроса

Comment: Извините, что не отвечаю @andreymal Просто возможно изменились  настройки в самой консоли.  console {debug: ƒ, error: ƒ, info: ƒ, log: ƒ, warn: ƒ, …} <-- Тут как-то можно изменить? И что у вас выводит в консоли, когда вы прописываете console ?

Comment: @vihtor Я в поле поиска не вводил Filter

Comment: сбрось настройки консоли...

Comment: @air Как сбросить? или как задать какие-то настройки ей?ведь это случайно вышло и я сам не понимаю.

Comment: открой консоль нажми F1  и в самом низу найдешь

Comment: @Air Спасибо, помогло, но как изменить эти настройки(console {debug: ƒ, error: ƒ, info: ƒ, log: ƒ, warn: ƒ, …})? Из за чего оно случилось?

Comment: честно не знаю,  у меня так же было...  после 5 минут размышления, это единственное что пришло в голову и мне помогло)))